# Fallback to swiffy-generated html5 ad?

Tags: html, flash, google-swiffy

We converted several Flash ads to Swiffy's HTML5 format.

Now we're wondering where to put html5 code in this general  tag so it will be used when no flash available.

Maybe the bottom where the get_flash_player.gif is rendered is the right place? Question is how to implement fallback.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-250by500">

  <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="250" height="500" id="250x500" align="middle" class="embed-responsive-item">
    <param name="movie" value="<%= asset_path('hyundai_tucson_250x500.swf?clickTAG=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hyundai.sk%2Fmodely%2Ftucson%3Futm_source%3Dautozurnal%26utm_medium%3Ddoublesquare%26utm_content%3D250_500%26utm_campaign%3D11477_Hyundai_Tucson_launch') %>" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<%= asset_path('hyundai_tucson_250x500.swf?clickTAG=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hyundai.sk%2Fmodely%2Ftucson%3Futm_source%3Dautozurnal%26utm_medium%3Ddoublesquare%26utm_content%3D250_500%26utm_campaign%3D11477_Hyundai_Tucson_launch') %>" width="250" height="500">
      <param name="movie" value="<%= asset_path('hyundai_tucson_250x500.swf?clickTAG=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hyundai.sk%2Fmodely%2Ftucson%3Futm_source%3Dautozurnal%26utm_medium%3Ddoublesquare%26utm_content%3D250_500%26utm_campaign%3D11477_Hyundai_Tucson_launch') %>" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
      <param name="play" value="true" />
      <param name="loop" value="true" />
      <param name="wmode" value="window" />
      <param name="scale" value="showall" />
      <param name="menu" value="true" />
      <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
      <param name="salign" value="" />
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
      <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
      </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
  </object>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already converted your Flash Ads to HTML5, why would/should you want to use the Flash version anymore? Just use the HTML5 and you won't need a fallback at all.

Comment: Because html5 ads I have converted are not snappy on mobile devices. Everytime I scroll on the ad it is loading again from scratch and scroll gesture is completelly lagging (tested on iPhone 6 Plus and some Android devices) And battery drain on my smartphone is noticable. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is on how you build the ad / the tech behind it. Try using Greensock as your primary animation enabler ( instead of relying on Swiffy conversion ) and integrate fastclick to take care of the scroll gestures. You'll probably have to post your creative somewhere so we can take a look at how it's built before I can make further suggestions.